# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'

Tags: c, pointers, char

```
graphics_draw_text(ctx, s_time_text, s_font, bounds, GTextOverflowModeWordWrap, GTextAlignmentLeft, NULL);take the address with &.  

Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'
```

All I want is for the text I'm drawing on my canvas to display the time,  **s_time_text**.
I understand basic data types but pointers still confuse the hell out of me. It works fine if I'm using a normal text layer, but it seems to be when I'm drawing text on a canvas layer it gets upset. Below is a snippet with relevant parts.

```
void graphics_draw_text(GContext *ctx, const char *text, GFont const font, 
    const GRect box, const GTextOverflowMode overflow_mode, const GTextAlignment alignment,
    GTextAttributes *text_attributes);

static char s_time_text;


static void prv_handle_minute_tick(struct tm *tick_time, TimeUnits units_changed)
{
    char s_time_text[] = "00:00";
    char *time_format = clock_is_24h_style() ? "%H:%M" : "%I:%M";
    strftime(s_time_text, sizeof(s_time_text), time_format, tick_time);
}

static void canvas_update_proc(Layer *layer, GContext *ctx) {
    s_font = fonts_load_custom_font(resource_get_handle(RESOURCE_ID_FREEMONO_18));
    GRect bounds = GRect(0, 0, 60, 20);
    graphics_context_set_text_color(ctx, GColorBlack);
    graphics_draw_text(ctx, s_time_text, s_font, bounds, GTextOverflowModeWordWrap, GTextAlignmentLeft, NULL);
}
```

Comment: What's going on with `s_time_text`? Is it a `static char` or a `char[]` array?

Comment: Please show us the prototype of `graphics_draw_text`.

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage it is obvious.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie void graphics_draw_text(GContext * ctx, const char * text, GFont const font, const GRect box, const GTextOverflowMode overflow_mode, const GTextAlignment alignment, GTextAttributes * text_attributes)

Comment: Why do you have two variables called `s_time_text`, with very different types?

Comment: s_time_text must be const char pointer,but you've set static char variable here.

Comment: Not only does the char variable have the wrong type, it is also not updated whenever `prv_handle_minute_tick` is called as the variable name is hidden by local variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare `s_time_text` twice one time in the global context as char , second time in the function `prv_handle_minute_tick` as local char [] variable.

If it has to be visible in this compilation unit (file) scope remove the second one and amend the global one to:

```
  static char s_time_text[]= "00:00";
```

but remember - it is only 6 characters long (including ending zero)

Comment: I LOVE YOU! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `graphics_draw_text` function is expecting a `char *` for its second parameter

```
graphics_draw_text(GContext * ctx, const char * text, GFont const font, const GRect box, const GTextOverflowMode overflow_mode, const GTextAlignment alignment, GTextAttributes * text_attributes)
```

But `s_time_text` is declared as a file-global `char`.

```
static char s_time_text;
```

The `s_time_text` in the scope of the `canvas_update_proc` function is not the one you declare in the `prv_handle_minute_tick` function.

Comment: Ok what you're saying makes sense. How would I globally declare the 's_time_text' in 'canvas_update_proc'?

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, what happens is that the compiler substitutes the global `char s_time_text` in the call to `graphics_draw_text(ctx, s_time_text, ..`, but first promotes this `char` to `int`, and then complains that the integer cannot be converted to a pointer.